# Trying to display a PDF File using Swift under MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, pdf

I am a hobbyist, and am porting an application that I originally developed under Visual Studio (Windows, C#) to Xcode using Swift under MacOS.  I am trying to display the contents of an existing PDF file when I pull up the Help menu.  From researching the internet, I gather that I should be able to do this using NSView or NSViewController.

I have found solutions that work (more or less) under iOS, but have not yet found a solution under MacOS.

Here's the code that I've currently implemented.

When I activate "Usage" under the application's Help menu item, the application executes the following code:

```
func usage(method: String) -> String
{
    ViewController()
}
```

For ViewController, I found the following online:

```
import AppKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: NSViewController
{

  @IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf")
    {
      if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
      {
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The document "sample.pdf" is not display, and it appears that the override function is never executed.

I am new to Swift and am just learning the language.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your app have a window? If you don't have a window, you need to make one. Otherwise, show the PDF in the window e.g. by setting its `contentViewController`.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Yes, I do have a Window.  I've set up the code so that when I press a button in the Window, it activates the usage() function above.  How do I set contentViewController?  Can you point me toward something online?